# Remove Automatic UTM parameters Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-analytics

There are some additional parameters added to my UTM parameters within links I want to get removed like:
cm_ven=ExactTarget&cm_cat=%%EmailName_%%&cm_pla=%%ListName%%&cm_ite=%%LinkName%%&cm_lm=%%EmailAddr_%%&cm_ainfo=%%AdditionalInfo_%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute2%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute3%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute4%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute5%%

Salesforce support says they are added automatically by the Web Analytics Connector code. I Told support to only add 1 utm parameter which is visible in parameter management. How do I remove the cm_ parameters and the __AdditionalEmailAttribute parameters. Salesforce support cant seem to help me.. [image] Thanks!

Comment: Is this in a triggeredsend or jb send?  If so pause publish start the send again

Comment: Its Marketing Cloud in General, but we only use JB sends. So I should go through all journeys and do this +40?

Comment: So changes to the wac string don’t get applied to running triggeredsends. It appears you have atleast one triggeredsend using the old value. You can go to email studio > triggered sends > journey builder sends and do these actions in bulk. This will the. Apply the current WAC string and remove the old

Comment: Thanks allot! will do it. Thanks for the quick answer